# MVVM and Navigation in Silverlight

Tags: mvvm, navigation, silverlight-5.0

Suppose I'm using the MVVM approach (Silverlight)

I'm having all my buttons handled with commands.

Suppose I have a button used to navigate to a certain page, say we selected a customer in a grid and want to navigate to the customer's details view.

Can I handle this button with a DelegateCommand? How? Can I handle the navigation from the ViewModel? Am I forced to handle the navigation from the code-behind.

Comment: How do you navigate from page to page currently?  Do you have a navigation service of some kind?  If you would provide some code that would be very useful.

Comment: Now I'm using the code-behind approach:
      `private void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/CustomerDetails", UriKind.Relative));
      }`

Comment: Open question: is navigation really a part of the ViewModel, or is it an implementation detail of the View? If the latter, you can stick to using code-behind, or HyperlinkButton, as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

Xaml:

```
<Button Command="{Binding GoToCustomerDetailsPage}" Content="Customer Details"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private INavigationService _navigationService;

public ViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    _navigationService=navigationService;
}
public ICommand GoToCustomerDetailsPage
{
    get{
        return new DelegateCommand(GoToCustDetailsPage,CanGoToCustDetailsPage);
        }
}

private void GoToCustDetailsPage()
{
    _navigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/CustomerDetails", UriKind.Relative));
}

private bool CanGoToCustDetailspage()
{
   return true;//Or some sensible code that determines if this is sensible.
}
```

Basically, the Command is bound to the button as per normal.  The command is a property on the viewmodel.  When the Command is executed it simply calls a private method in the viewmodel.

Comment: In what dll is INavigationService located?, I use NavigationService in a Page, and Page has a navigationService declaration, but how do I do it in the ViewModel?

Comment: I think I partially resolved it with your suggestion. I used NavigationService instead of INavigationService in the viewmodel constructor and set an usings statement to System.Windows.Navigation, but this version of the constructor is not being used when I click the navigating button, so, my navigationService variable is null!!

Comment: When you are instantiating your viewmodel how are you passing in your navigation service?  E.g:  new ViewModel(NavigationService) where NavigationService is an instance of your navigation service object.

Comment: Thank you, I see that I have to make the interface.

For other viewers, you can get more info in http://garfoot.com/blog/2010/09/silverlight-navigation-with-the-mvvm-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

here INavigationService not available.. It gives error if we add the namespace System.Windows.Navigation..